# Why $\mathbb{P}(X>n)=q^n$ in geomtric distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim G(p)$

> Why $\mathbb{P}(X>n)=q^n$ in geomtric distribution?

I know that $\mathbb{P}(X=n)=(1-p)^{n-1}p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An intuitive reasoning: a geometric distribution gives the probability that you get the first success (whose probability is $p=1-q$) at the $n$-th trial. So, the probability that $X>n$ is the probability to have no success at all in the first $n$ trials.

More rigorously: 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[X>n]&=1-\mathbb{P}[X\le n]\\
&=1-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}[X=i]\right)\\
&=1-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}q^{i-1}(1-q)\right)\\
&=1-(1-q)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}q^{i-1}\right)\\
&=1-(1-q)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}q^{j}\right)\\
&=1-(1-q)\frac{1-q^{n}}{1-q}\\
&=q^{n}
\end{align}$$